# Done Rewriting with lighttpd

Tags: url, url-rewriting, lighttpd

since yesterday, I have a problem when I try to make rewriting URL. I want to transform the following adress:

https://url.com/dir/?src=user.home/56

to 
https://url.com/dir/user/home/56

help me please. thank you

PS: LIGHTTPD and not apache.

Answer (score 0):

'/' is a special character which is likely encoded as %2f or %2F, so you need to handle that when matching lighttpd conditions against the query string.

https://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/lighttpd/wiki/Docs_ModRewrite

    `$HTTP["query-string"] =~ "user.home(?:/|%2(?:f|F))(\d+)" {
      url.rewrite-once = ( "^/dir/" => "/dir/user/home/%1" )
    }`